# How to pass a javascript variable to php without opening a new page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a user enter a value in a form and `onClick()` activates a function that takes the URL the user pasted and cuts it down (using an algorithm I made, but that is irrelevant). I end up with a string of 11 characters and im not sure how to get this to a php page that submits it to my database. The way i am doing it now takes the browser to a new page and i want the user to stay on the same page.

```
function findvideoid(){
   window.location.href = 'submitvid.php?videoID=' + videoID;
}
```

Comment: **[jQuery Ajax^](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

Comment: @CodeAngry Why jQuery? Nobody needs it just for its AJAX helper functions!

Comment: @ComFreek Because Ajax is easy with jQuery. Based on his question, he'll need that easy part.

Comment: You can download this my pure javascript basic ajax code here: http://www.ulozto.net/xSf4Aap/ajaxpost-zip And here is very good tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp (and "w3fools" please don't spam, if you have nothing constructive to say)

Comment: @Stano Really... login just for that? :) **github** or **pastebin** it, don't be funny.

Comment: @CodeAngry No login is required, just click Download, "rewrite the antispam code from picture" and click Download again.

Comment: @Stano, please see http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @gion_13 I know that page and understand its purpose. But please don't spam. [This tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp) is ok. Or did you find there something wrong? If so tell us directly, don't be prejudiced against w3schools.

Comment: I wasn't referring to that particular page. I didn't want to start a whole discussion out of this - it was just a comment and not spam. All I wanted to say is that you shouldn't encourage/initiate people to use that site. I'm not prejudiced about w3schools, I do have objective reasons not to use it.

Comment: @CodeAngry there are just two simple files zipped: .php and .js so I put it on filesharing server.

Comment: @Stano Pleae fix your security holes (outputting unescaped $_POST data) before sharing such code.

Comment: @ComFreek It is just one example I learned with a few months ago on localhost, but thanks for your warning. Can be easily added some additional [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function to it.

Comment: @ComFreek **You're right!** It's downloadable but I still don't get it why you put it there. Anyways, that example works for this case... but that's far from a proper Ajax reusable implementation. But it works here.

Comment: @CodeAngry [It](http://www.ulozto.net/xSf4Aap/ajaxpost-zip) is not reusable library, only simple "ajax example" (how to send/receive data to/from server). For OP it could be better to use some [ligtweight ajax library](https://www.google.com/search?q=lightweight+ajax+library). [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) is great, but not for single-use purpose due to its size. (just like ComFreek say in his answer)

Answer (score 3):

Pure JavaScript solution (recommended):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhr.readyStatus == 4) { // finished
    if (xhr.status == 200) { // 200 HTTP code returned by server
    }
    else { // error
    }
  }
};
xhr.open("GET", "your-script.php?videoID=" + encodeURIComponent(videoID));
xhr.send(null);
```

jQuery solution (recommended if you already use jQuery in your project or if you want to try it out):

```
// PHP script can access $_GET['videoID']
jQuery.get("your-script.php?videoID=" + encodeURIComponent(videoID));

// PHP script can access $_POST['videoID']
jQuery.post("your-script.php", {videoID: videoID});
```

[jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

[jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: @Petah you mean, like, IE7 and older? Do you really wish to support these?

Comment: Even IE 7 supports it! See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505(v=vs.85).aspx)! This is no reason to downvote.

Comment: +1 from me. Death to old browsers! :) We need to enforce evolution, **coerce users into updating**. That's my motto!

Answer (score 2):

What about masking the actual ajax call with the loading of an external html resource?
If no real callback is expected, you could inject an iframe into the document pointing to the specified url and then remove it from the document.

Here's an example of accessing your backend's api url masked by loading an image:

```
function findvideoid(id, callback){
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = callback;
    img.src = apiUrl + '?videoId=' + encodeURIComponent(id) 
              + '&antiCache=' + new Date().getTime();
}
```

No ajax. No other libs. Google does it for it's analytics. Why shouldn't you?

Comment: It could be possible that the browser caches the URI, couldn't it?

Comment: Really? downvote for that? See update: now the browser will NEVER cache the url.

Comment: **I did not downvote you**! I just commented because I (we) do not know the specific use case of the OP.

Answer (score -1):

Use AJAX:

```
function findvideoid()
{
  var html = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "submitvid.php",
    data: "videoID=" + videoID,
    async: false
  }).responseText;

  if(html == "success")
  {     
    // Uncomment the following line in your application
    //return true;
  }
  else
  {     
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` jQuery is not standart

Comment: @JanDvorak lets just be happy you dont control the ecmagroup then :)

Comment: `As of jQuery 1.8, the use of  async: false  with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback` from [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score -2):

You can do this easily in jQuery

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: also, you must not return all the html.

Comment: @AkseliKoskinen I cannot speak for the downvoters but you're assuming that the OP already uses jQuery or wants to include it.